# Как можно получить список доступных (pub) элементов модуля, указав его полное имя?

Tags: rust, reverse-engineering, mod

Пожалуйста, приведите пример вывода списка доступных элементов модуля (struct, enum, const, ...).

Например, я хотел бы знать, действительно ли у модуля `std::u8` в открытом доступе есть только две коснтанты? Может быть функции тоже есть?

Comment: Если это нужно как помощь во время написания кода, стоит попробвать [Rust Language Server](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rls).

Comment: Судя по описанию возможностей - решение хорошее (но нестабильное со слов разработчиков). Да и громоздкое (целый языковой сервер поднимать). Но надо будет обязательно попробовать. 

Может быть есть какие-либо `usave`-решения?

Comment: Language Server Protocol это рекомендуемое решение Microsoft для поддержки языков программирования независимо от среды разработки.
RLS не такой уж и громоздкий, у меня в открытом небольшом проекте с графом зависимостей в 5-10 крейтов занимает в памяти меньше 15 мегабайт. Preview-версия доступна и в стабильном канале rustup, но поскольку проект пока в стадии инкубации, там могут не быть реализованы новые полезные возможности.

Answer (score 1):

Вся документация по доступным элементам крейта генерируется автоматически, командой `cargo doc`

Документация модуля `std::u8` находится [здесь](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/u8/).

Comment: Это, конечно, хороший способ, но весьма ограниченный, т.к. документация, к примеру, модуля `std::u8` (ссылку на которую Вы привели) содержит только описание двух констант, а если к модулю обратиться с помощью конструкции `<u8>::`,  можно получить доступ к методам, названия которых можно увидеть только, если посмотреть исходники. Было бы удобно воспользоваться каким-нибудь методом (готовым решением, чтобы в [http://play.rust-lang.org/](http://play.rust-lang.org/)  посмотреть то, что нужно.

Comment: Вот пример доступа к функции: `let min:u8 = <u8>::min_value();`

Comment: Это не обращение к модулю, а вызов функции ассоциированной с типом. Документация по этим функциям: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u8.html

Comment: Понятно. @red75prim, cпасибо!